# Calling methods with parameter class of an element from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here is the master file:

```
<li id="notification0">
    <a href="#" onclick="/MyPage/MyPageView"></a>
</li>
<li id="notification1">
    <a href="#" onclick="/MyPage/MyPageView"></a>
</li>
<li id="notification2">
    <a href="#" onclick="/MyPage/MyPageView"></a>
</li>
```

And then, with javascript and jquery I add text and classes to the links.
I want to call the MyPageView function in MyPageController with that class as parameter. What should i change in the onclick to add the class as argument? But I am getting and adding the class later in the code.

I want to do this:

```
onclick="/MyPage/MyPageView/classForTheCorrectNotificationTag"
```

This is how I add the class:

```
$('#notification0').addClass('test');
$('#notification1').addClass('water');
$('#notification2').addClass('driver');
```

Comment: When you add the text and class name to the link, also attach the event handler, rather than add it inline.  Show us the code that adds the text and class and we can then suggest how to modify it to suit.

Comment: As @Archer says, please post the code which is adding the classes - it's at this point you need to add the click handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the base controller path as a common value, you can simply have that as a global variable:

```
var controllerPath = "/MyPage/MyPageView/";
```

Then you can just add the click event at the same time you add the class:

```
$('#notification0').addClass('test').click(function(e) {
    window.location.href = controllerPath + 'test';
});
```

Depending on how your classes need to be added this could probably be made to be more dynamic such as:

```
function SetClickable(id, path) {
    $('#' + id).addClass(path).click(function(e) {
        window.location.href = controllerPath + path;
    });
}
```

If the primary controller path is not a constant, you may want to attempt to use data attributes to contain it:

```
<li id="notification0" data-controller="/MyPage/MyPageView/">
    <a href="#"></a>
</li>

function SetClickable(id, path) {
    $('#' + id).addClass(path).click(function(e) {
        var controller = $(this).data("controller");
        window.location.href = controller + action;
    });
}
```